# Chrome обрезает изображение android

Tags: android, изображения, google-chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В других браузерах все ок, не могу понять в чем причина
css код на изображении:

```
position: absolute;
left: 17px;
background-position: 17px center;
top: calc(-3.125vw + 150px);
max-width: calc(87.1875vw + 21px);
max-height: calc(39.5625vw + 128.4px);
min-width: 246px;
min-height: 255px;
```

Comment: Если бы это было приложение, то надо было бы изменить стиль фото, но это же сайт, Вам в другой раздел. И вообще, у Вас высота 255, возможно, если сменить на 300, к примеру, оно не будет обрезать ?

Comment: Без разницы, высоту менял, само изображение обрезается, не css

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size:contain;
```

или

```
background-size:cover;
```

Вы не задаете размеров изображению, так что это ожидаемая реакция. Если изображение задано backgroundом

Comment: Пробовал, выводил просто изображение, не бекграундом, всё равно обрезается само изображение. И CSS не режет изображение, проверил несколько раз

Comment: Кроме css нечему это сделать. Разве что вы установили размеры изображения жёстко. Возможно у вас стоит overflow:hidden в блоке, где находится картинка